# PhpStorm How to customize the browser icon URL

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm to develop PHP and use the thinkphp framework. Because the framework has its own URL rules, PhpStorm cannot parse the URL according to the context. The default URL accessed by PhpStorm by clicking the browser icon is `https://ppgjx.com/application/functions/controller/Index.php`

[image]

This is inaccessible, according to the rules of the framework, normal access should be like this: `https://ppgjx.com/functions/index`

[image]

Development is very inconvenient. Is there any way to solve this problem so that PhpStorm can access the URL correctly?

[image]

Comment: Try setting up path mappings in deployment server configuration. E.g. for `application/functions/controller/index.php` path set `functions/index` Web path.

Comment: Just as Dmitrii said: when you use "Open in Browser" functionality (that includes that browser icons bar) it takes info about URL from the **default** Deployment entry. Deployment allows you to specify **multiple** mapping rules ... so you can create one for `domain.com/functions/` and it will be uploading to `domain.com/application/functions/controller/` folder. But since your URLs do not have `.php` there you would need to create such mapping for every file... which is inconvenient. Instead just use bookmarks in your browser... or Run/Debug Configuration of the appropriate type (per URL).